# PHP IoC cross dependencies

Tags: php, dependencies, inversion-of-control, containers, ioc-container

So we've got a container, service providers and, with inversion of control, we can  do fancy stuff like:

```
public function __construct(CarServiceInterface $carService)
{
}
```

And things get resolved nicely because somewhere else...

```
$container->bind(CarServiceInterface::class, function ()
{
    return new CarService();
});
```

Let's say car service depends on human service. Then...

```
    $container->bind(CarServiceInterface::class, function (Container $container)
    {
        return new CarService($container->make(HumanServiceInterface::class);
    });
```

Hey, that works. Cool.

But then suddenly humans NEED cars, and the human service is built like this:

```
$container->bind(HumanServiceInterface::class, function (Container $container)
{
   return new HumanService($container->make(CarServiceInterface::class);
});
```

Voila, cross dependency.

How to solve this?

Is this consequence of a flaw in the design?

Thanks!

Comment: Co-dependence is not healthy

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be called 'Circular dependencies' (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076299/circular-dependency-injecting-objects-that-are-directly-depended-on-each-other) for more about this).

The answer says that there's no way to do this, and that the only way to use a circular dependency is to use setter injection, instead of the usual constructor injection.

Comment: This is a good answer. Human's don't _need_ cars, but if one's available they certainly could use one.

Comment: @watcher Thanks, and I agree, if you compare it to a real-life scenario, it makes a lot of sense as well.